# basic theming question on user module

Tags: theming

I would like to ask a very simple (for you probably!) question on theming/layout:

By default the user module displayes the "username" + "password" vertically.
I want to display these 2 fields horizontally.

To do so:

-It is the css that I have to modify, right?
-Do i have to modify the user.css or the css of my theme?
-Any ideas on how do I modify it, or what is the piece of code I have to alter?

Thank you.

Comment: you have to modify in your theme folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you have to modify the **css** file for the changes to be reflected,but the **change should not be** made in the **core** css files.
2. You can replace any of the core css settings by entering the **specific id's and classes's** of the elements which you would like to **change** into a custom **css file** in your theme's folder.
3. It will **override** the **individual css** settings of that element.
4. Make certain that the file is **identified** as a stylesheet in the **info** file for the theme .(**include the custom css file which you have created in your site's theme's folder in the .info file**)

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed answer, thank you very much.

Comment: In fact I wanted to discuss something with you (not for free of course) Could you please let me know a way to contact you or send me an email: apdr39 AT gmail DOT com

Answer (score 1):

You can extend [Omega Theme](https://drupal.org/node/1447700) and override the css in your `global.css` file. So you will have  a new theme and core files are intact.

All you need to install is  [Omega Theme](https://drupal.org/project/omega). And the By going to `Appearence` you can create a new theme and override the css files.

Comment: Your welcome..if you like it you can like it..;) anytime

Answer (score 0):

You should add the styling to your theme's css file.  Never edit the core files, always override them with your theme files.

Comment: Any ides on what do I have to modify there?! :)

Comment: Are you looking to modify the fields in the user-login form or the user block?

Comment: only the 2 fields (username and password) - just to put them horizontally instead of vertically..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom theme follow the steps to modify the CSS

1. goto path var/www/ursite/sites/all/themes/your_theme/css
2. here add file global.css
3. write the modified css in global.css file.
4. save the global .css file

in order to pre-test the changes use chromo web tool , if you are using google chrome .